# JS script defer is breaking code, would like to add callback or find another solution

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jwplayer, ruby-on-rails-6

I used the below code to load a JS script library and when the dom is loaded, I call my JS Helper

#### HTML

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://cdn.jwplayer.com/libraries/abcdefg.js', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', defer: true %>
```

#### Javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    player = jwplayer('myvideoplayer').setup(options);
});
```

However, when I set defer to true, the video player does not load currently.  I know I can set defer to false and have it work, but I want to defer the script.

Is it possible to create a call back or something after the script loads?
Is there an even listener can can execute after the script loads?

What options do I have?

Comment: Are you getting a console error when your ``DOMContentLoaded`` handler fires? What's the error?

Comment: My understanding is that ``defer`` scripts should load before the ``DOMContentLoaded`` event is fired, but try using ``turbolinks:load`` as the event instead and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: DomContentLoaded - `Uncaught TypeError: jwplayer is not a function`, turbolinks:load did not work